# Collapse rows inside a row in a table

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with several rows. When I click on a plus sign it should collapse new rows from that clicked row.

The problem is that those new rows are fetched by AJAX and need a "row container" to be appended to. How can I insert rows inside a row?

[image]

I can't just do this,

```
<tr class="builds">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">build1 product</td>
    <td>build1 events</td>
    <td>build1 actions</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">build2 product</td>
    <td>build2 events</td>
    <td>build2 actions</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
```

EDIT: Just to clarify. The main table is populated by AJAX, and when a row is clicked (and contains data) it should collapse rows below that clicked row. This is my main structure:

```
<div id="products" class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th>Customer <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th>API_KEY<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th># Events <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="products-container"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="more">+ More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unless i am blind what is the difference between the two divs?

Comment: did you built this table from scratch or used any jquery table plugins?

Comment: why are you adding the rows through ajax? Could you print the rows inbetween the clickables and add a hide class to them? then use javascript or jquery to toggle hide on plus or minus?

Comment: this might be too messy or too many tables for you but what if you had a blank row with a cell that has colspan on it. then within the files you call through ajax have a table already made so when you call ajax all you have to do is print the response to the blank row/cell below the selected row and when you reselect it use query slide to hide it again?

Comment: You cannot have a row inside a row, that is not valid HTML. However, you can insert a new row *after* the specified row.

Comment: Vimalan, I made the structure from scratch. Later it should be sortable with tablesorter.js library

Comment: xxstevenxo, the rows inbetween should be populated by ajax when requested, that was just a performance decision... Inserting those rows after the specified row would be a little dirty but could work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use jquery like this

normally you put the above code in your ajax request

```
$.ajax({ options }).done(function (data) {
   $.each(data,function(){
      $('parent row tag id').after('<tr><td>ajax content</td></tr>');
   });   
}
```

note that this code might need some altering but you should get the idea.

Comment: in that case you would be appending your new ajax content (tr's) inside your parent row (tr)

Comment: not what i'd like to have (i.e container), but very simple workaround for this